# Is data validation in Shopify templates or elsewhere?

Tags: shopify

We're using the Shopify API to grab data from orders, but we're having some trouble with data validation on the fulfillment side. Is there any way we can add data validation to our checkout page? Even just Javascript validation would be a huge improvement. By the time we see an error, the customer is out of the loop, so we're having to make assumptions about our user's data which is potentially dangerous.

One example is that user typed in a phone number that began with a 1 e.g. (xxx)-1xx-xxxx, which is invalid. Another typed an address that was too long for the shipping API we send it to. We don't want to truncate arbitrary addresses so is there a way to present an error to the customer?

Answer (score 2):

The checkout server is a black box as far as the API is concerned. This is mainly for security reasons.

Unfortunately, this prevents you from doing the kind of extra validation you're asking about during the checkout process.